# Get absolute URL inside Web API Controller?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

In my Controller I can't use `CreatedAtAction` for reasons out of the scope of this question.
I therefore need to do the following, however I don't know how to get the absolute URL of the Web API to  correctly set the `Location` header?

```
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> PostItem(ItemPostRequest itemPostRequest)
{
    // call repository etc.

    string baseUrl= // <------- how to get this?
    Response.Headers.Add("Location", baseUrl + insertId);

    return Content(savedItem, "application/json", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

I am on .NET 5.0, in case this matters.

Answer (score 4):

```
string baseUrl = $"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host.Value}/{Request.Path}";
```

Comment: thanks, that looks promising after first tests. Note that `Request.Path` can contain a trailing slash. Wondering if one has to check this manually or there is a more comfortable solution

Answer (score 0):

Stefan, I cannot add a comment due to low rep, so to add on to the answer from Prasad in your search of a more comfortable solution regarding the trailing slash - this is what I use:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace GeddesCapital.Blas.Api.Controllers
{
    public abstract class BaseControllerInheritedByAllMyControllers : ControllerBase
    {
        protected string BaseUrl => $"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host.Value}";

        protected string EndpointUrl => $"{BaseUrl}/{Request.Path.ToString().Trim('/')}";
    }
    
    [Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
    public class TestController : BaseControllerInheritedByAllMyControllers
    {
        [HttpPost("named-test-endpoint")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult SomeTestEndpoint()
        {
            const string trailingUrl = "/api/v1/Test/named-test-endpoint";
            
            var absoluteUrl1 = $"{BaseUrl}{trailingUrl}";
            var absoluteUrl2 = $"{EndpointUrl}";

            Console.WriteLine($"The two paths match each other: {absoluteUrl1 == absoluteUrl2}");

            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```